# XCode 5 View Debugging Feature

Tags: xcode5

I just installed xcode 5 and wanted to try the new "View  Debugging" feature.
Clicking on the eye-icon of an UIView in the debugger, does not bring up a graphical representation of the view, as shown at WWDC 2013 in the session about "What's new in Xcode".

Does somebody know how to activate this feature ? I'am thinking it might be related to the menu "Debug/View Debugging/.." but those options are all greyed out for me.
Anybody can help ?

Thanks a lot

Markus

Comment: Thanks. I'am in fact using the GM version, thinking it would be stable enough. I will wait then for the real stuff. By the way it also seems that a graph drawn with Coreplot is not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work for me (Xcode 5 DP 6 under Mavericks DP 7).  I didn't need to turn anything on:

[image]

I hovered over `size`, waited for the popup and then selected the *eye icon*.

Comment: You are right, with a variable of type CGSize it works also for me. However it does not work with UIView !

Comment: @user1755189 You might want to try <the view's name>.bounds