# Display value of a variable using Xcode breakpoint logging (LLDB)

Tags: xcode, macos, lldb

I have an array which I would like to print out in a breakpoint. I have read about how to do this with @exp@, so I've created a Log Message breakpoint like so:

```
%B %H count: @(NSUInteger)[myArray count]@ objects: @(const char *)[[myArray description] UTF8String]@
```

And here's what that prints:

```
-methodName: 33 count: 1 objects: 0x6dec5890
```

From everything I've read, this should print out a string containing the objects in myArray. And yet, clearly that's not happening. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using LLDB on Xcode 5.0.2. And if it matters, the app is 32-bit.

Comment: I could reproduce your problem. It seems that the "Breakpoint Log Message" feature has several problems. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059919/how-to-create-a-breakpoints-log-message-action-in-xcode for another problem, with a possible workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the commiseration. Indeed, I couldn't get the logging to work so this is what I ended up going with in a Debugger Command: `expr (void)NSLog(@"%@ -- count:%u objects [%@]", (NSString *)NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), (unsigned)[myArray count], myArray)` Of course, this doesn't give me the breakpoint count. `:-(`

Comment: If anyone at Apple cares, I've filed radar://15663740.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in recent versions of Xcode. (I'm on 6.1.1) Now you just need to put an array's name in between @s to get the expected output. No casting needed!

```
%B %H count: @myArray.count@ objects: @myArray.description@
```

Output:

```
-applicationDidFinishLaunching: 1 count: 2 objects: @"(\n    one,\n    two\n)"
```

A little messy with the encoded newlines, but at least it works!

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a Python breakpoint action that prints the variables you care about, and then automatically continues?

Comment: Care to provide some code which explains what you mean? Be sure to specify whether it's using a Debugger Command action or a Log Message action. I'd prefer the latter, since it has access to the %B count variable.

Answer (score -2):

I can't understand what you are doing. 
When I want to print or preview a variable in my code, I add a breakpoint just after my variable. When the breakpoint is reached, I just move the pointer over the name of the variable and a little window will appear where I can see the content of your variable.

Take a look at this answer: [XCode 5 View Debugging Feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810591/xcode-5-view-debugging-feature)

Comment: Thank you, but the variables I'm looking for data about can be hit multiple times per second. Unfortunately, breaking on each one and hovering isn't practical in my case.